# Error with go cross-compilation: unsupported GOOS/GOARCH pair linux /amd64

Tags: go, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile go code on windows, targeting linux machine.
I have used simple go code to determine target os/platform,

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "runtime"

func main() {
        fmt.Printf("OS: %s\nArchitecture: %s\n", runtime.GOOS, runtime.GOARCH)
}
```

Running above code gives me

```
OS: linux
Architecture: amd64
```

hovever when I try to cross compile on windows (using JetBrain's Goland IDE) with

```
> go version
go version go1.9.2 windows/amd64
```

using `GOOS=linux ;GOARCH=amd64` environment flags, I get following error

```
cmd/go: unsupported GOOS/GOARCH pair linux /amd64
```

I am new to golang, so I might be missing something simple, but this error got me stuck. Any help appreciated...

Comment: Remove the extra space after `linux`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like your GOOS is getting set to "linux ", not "linux".

Comment: That was it. Thanks @hobbs, an extra pair of eyes can save a day!

Comment: I have had the same issue but I set it go env -w with an empty space but it messed and when I try to update it. it doesn't let me with the command. Is there a way I can manually fix this?

Comment: I had a space appended behind the line `export GOOS=linux` in the Makefile. However stupid this mistake might look like, if I had not found this post, I would have probably lost a lot of time...

Comment: My error was my bash script was literally printing out the curly braces instead of processing them.

Comment: Very surprising what a pertinent question this is; seems like a simple typo but in fact Go on Windows is quite sensitive to spaces! Glad I found this