# Makefile Error on Windows: Unsupported GOOS/GOARCH pair linux/amd64 When Building Go Project

Tags: windows, go, aws-lambda, makefile

I'm working on a Go project on a Windows machine and trying to use a `Makefile` to build multiple Go Lambda functions for deployment to AWS. My project structure is set up with each Lambda function in a separate directory under `src/functions`, and each has its own `main.go`. I'm encountering an issue when running my Makefile's build command in PowerShell through VS Code terminal.

Foler structure

```
/project-root
  /cdk.out
  /src
    /functions
      /hello
        main.go
      /goodbye
        main.go
  Makefile
```

Here's the relevant part of my `Makefile`:

```
GOOS=linux
GOARCH=amd64

FUNCTIONS_DIR := src/functions
FUNCTIONS := $(notdir $(wildcard $(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/*))

build:
    @echo "Building functions..."
    @$(foreach func, $(FUNCTIONS), \
        GOOS=$(GOOS) GOARCH=$(GOARCH) go build -o $(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/$(func)/bootstrap $(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/$(func)/main.go; \
        echo "Built $(func)/bootstrap"; \
    )
```

When I run `make build`, I receive the following error:

```
"Building functions..."
go: unsupported GOOS/GOARCH pair linux /amd64 
make: *** [Makefile:25: build] Error 2
```

I am aware that environment variables in Windows should be set differently, and I've tried using both PowerShell and Command Prompt syntaxes with no success.

Here's what I have tried:

**PowerShell Syntax:**

```
build:
    @echo "Building functions..."
    @$(foreach func, $(FUNCTIONS), \
        $Env:GOOS='linux'; $Env:GOARCH='amd64'; go build -o $(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/$(func)/bootstrap $(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/$(func)/main.go; \
        echo "Built $(func)/bootstrap"; \
    )
```

**Command Prompt Syntax:**

```
build:
    @echo "Building functions..."
    @$(foreach func, $(FUNCTIONS), \
        set GOOS=linux && set GOARCH=amd64 && go build -o $(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/$(func)/bootstrap $(FUNCTIONS_DIR)/$(func)/main.go; \
        echo "Built $(func)/bootstrap"; \
    )
```

I've confirmed that Go is installed correctly, and the `go build` command works fine when run directly in the terminal for a single function directory.

How can I adjust my `Makefile` to correctly set environment variables and build my project on Windows?

Comment: `unsupported GOOS/GOARCH pair linux /amd64 ` -- you somehow have extra whitespace after `linux `

Comment: Is the error in your example shown exactly as it appeared in the command-line? `go: unsupported GOOS/GOARCH pair linux /amd64` has a space between `linux` and the `/`. Is a trailing space making its way into your env var?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48271030/13889413 this should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is *remove* the `@` at the beginning of your makefile recipes, so you can see the actual commands that are being invoked, and check carefully that they contain what you expect.  Using `@` is like running your compiler with output redirected to /dev/null so you can't see the output then trying to figure out what's wrong.

In your case, the problem is that `$` is a special character to make; it introduces a make variable.  So in this line:

```
$Env:GOOS='linux'; $Env:GOARCH='amd64'
```

the `$` is expanded by make and since `$E` is an empty variable, make will invoke:

```
nv:GOOS='linux'; nv:GOARCH='amd64'
```

which is wrong.  If you hadn't added the `@` then make would show you this incorrect text.

You need to double the dollar sign to escape it:

```
$$Env:GOOS='linux'; $$Env:GOARCH='amd64'
```